# Why doesn't my camera have curves in the graph editor?

Tags: camera, graph-editor

I've animated my camera but now I want to tweak the keyframes. However, when I select it and open the graph editor, there are no curves to tweak. Is there something else I need to do? I've used the graph editor with objects and had no issues, only now with the camera.

Comment: How was the camera animated? E.g. if with Follow Path contraint there won't necessarily be any keyframes.

Comment: It's just a very simple rotation and zoom using keyframes.

Comment: I worked it out. It was on a different layer. Even though I duplicated the camera to my layer, when you press 0 it must go to the original camera, not the one in your current layer.

Comment: Pressing Numpad 0 will bring you to the active camera no matter where it is. Do you mean you were selecting the wrong camera?

Comment: I was animating in Layer 2, while the camera itself was in Layer 1. I've now moved it over to Layer 2 and it's showing up in the graph editor.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out—The camera was actually on a different layer than the one I was using.